# Convert functions to async with python-telegram-bot library

Tags: python, bots, python-asyncio, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a Telegram bot that parses GTFS data and returns the user the status of subway trains. I'm using the python-telegram-bot library and, so far, the bot I created work as intended.

However, I wrote some very pandas rich functions that process pandas dataframes to obtain the train schedule. I've only just realized that these functions work normally if you have a single user request, otherwise, since they are *not* async, they are serialized and block subsequent requests (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've read that asyncio might be apt to it, but I can't make it work. What can I do in practice to async those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the sync function into an async function. Something like:

```
from functools import wraps

def make_async(sync_func):
    @wraps(sync_func)
    async def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return sync_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return async_func
```

This function takes as parameter a sync function and returns a corresponding async function.

Comment: Would this work also in the case where one of my sync functions calls another sync function?

Comment: Yes, it also covers this case

Comment: I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object` from the second asynced nested function. I guess because I don't await it, since the calling function is a sync one?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible script in your question so that I can reproduce, please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with v13 of PTB (python-telegram-bot) library you can pass [run_async=True](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.handler.html#telegram.ext.Handler.run_async) in your handlers, that will made your handlers run asynchrounously allowing multiple updates to be processed at same time.

Alternatively PTB is shifting towards async, you can use its [alpha release](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) which is fully asynchronous, pretty much stable and is future of PTB!
See [Concurrency in PTB](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency) if you are going to use v20